# How do I install packages on vscode on mac?

Tags: python, pip, package, visual-studio-code

I'm new to this and would really appreciate some help in the set up! So I'm trying to install packages on vscode on mac but I keep getting the error "no module named "matplotlib". I also tried pip install matplotlib in the terminal but I'm not sure if that's the cause of the problem.
Please see screenshot below. Would greatly appreciate some help!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think you want to `import numpy as np`? If you want to install a package from the terminal use `pip install numpy`.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this but still getting error. Please see my new screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed in the screenshot you provided: The python environment you are currently using in VScode is the global environment ("`python3.8.5`" in the lower left corner of the screenshot), but the terminal is in the virtual environment (`.venv`), so VSCode cannot find this module.

**Solution:**

1. You can use the shortcut key Ctrl+shift+ '  to open a new terminal, and VSCode will automatically enter the current global environment, and the module can be imported and used after installation with "`pip install matplotlib`":

   [image]
2. You can also choose this `.venv` environment with the `matplotlib` module installed:

   [image]

Reference: [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Comment: Thanks a lot Jill! How do I set up in virtual environment instead of the global environment in both terminal and python? I think it is better not to install something in the global environment to keep the flexibility, is it right?

Comment: @SoniaLo Yes, your intuition is correct. It‘s usually better to work in virtual environments. You can look [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) for detailed instructions.

Comment: @Sonia Lo You can use the shortcut key "Ctrl+Shift+p" and input "Python: Select Interpreter" to select the environment you need in the options.

Comment: Thanks a lot again Jill! You're really very helpful and kind!!

Answer (score 0):

Because of that you Installed the `anaconda`.so if you try to install new packages, you will be installing on the anaconda rather than your Python OS. you should be Deactivate `(base)`. follow these commands:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

close your terminal and open it again. Now you can install packages

Comment: Yes, I have anaconda but I tried your command on the terminal and it didn't work.